# Bootstrap Modal validation displaying on dismiss

Tags: angularjs, validation, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a form view in AngularJS and I'm using a modal from Angular-ui to display my form. Functionality wise, everything works great, however, when I dismiss the form, validation pop-ups display if the form is invalid.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The pop-up doesn't show at all when the form is open but only when I click cancel and it starts fading away.

HMTL:

```
<form name='newGroupForm'>
    <div class="modal-body">
            <label for="groupName">Group Name:
                <input id="groupName" type="text" ng-model='newGroup.name' required>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label for="groupDesc">Group Description:
                <input id="groupDesc" type="text" ng-model='newGroup.desc'>
            </label>
            <br/>
            <label for="groupOwner">Group Name:
                <select id="groupOwner" type="text"  ></select>
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="submit()" ng-disabled="newGroupForm.$invalid">Create</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Modal Controller:

```
spApp.controller('newGroupCtrl', 
    function newGroupCtrl($scope, $modalInstance, groupService){
        $scope.newGroup = {
            name:null,
            desc: null
        };

        $scope.submit = function(){
            $modalInstance.close($scope.newGroup);
        }
        $scope.cancel = function (){
            $modalInstance.dismiss('Cancelled group creation');
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the novalidate attribute to your form to disable the browsers built in validation:

```
<form name="myForm" novalidate >
```